Prepare gaming dataset - one-hot-encoding vs. min-max-normalization for card ids
I have a dataset for a game. 5 player cards with ids for player 1, 5 player cards with ids for player 2. Column names are like player1_card1_id, ..., player1_card5_id, player2_card1_id, ..., player2_card5_id and output like "winner" (1 or 2).
My idea was to one-hot encode the card ids, so that i have for every card id a column like player1_card_id_1,..., player1_card_id_200 and same for player 2.
A friend of mine suggested to just to min max normalization on the ids. Does this make any sense?
My aim is to do ML with it (decision tree, random forest, svm, gboost). I have a limited time to train sadly. One concern is, that the one-hot-encoded data set will take too long to train. Is this true? I have 400k rows and without the cards, 10 features. With one-hot-encoding it would be 410 features.
